# Edit starting and ending tag at same time

Tags: xml, eclipse

Is there a way to edit starting and ending tag at the same time?

For example rename :

```
<abc something="whatever"> ... more stuff here ... </abc>
```

To:

```
<abcdef something="whatever"> ... more stuff here ... </abcdef>
```

Without editing both starting and ending tag.

Comment: Doesn't the XML Editor offer to do that on Ctrl+1?

Comment: Thanks... I was expecting it at Shift+Alt+R, since it works in code and with files...

Anyway, that answers my question, so feel free to post it as answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML Editor provides this as a Quick Assist through Ctrl/Cmd+1.